# Indentation error: expected an indented block python 3.6

Tags: python, indentation

I am a newbie in python. I wanted to return string "shutting down" if `s==yes`. Pls tell me what could be wrong in the below code.

```
def shut_down(s):
... if s == "yes":
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    if s == "yes":
     ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: remove the dots `...` and use `4 spaces or one tabulation` for identation.

Comment: Is the dots in the code? Or you mix up tab and space?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please try to search the platform for similar problems and read the python doc before posting your question.

Comment: yes its the dots in the code(python 3.6 interpreter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr try to add 4 spaces to the start of your second line like this:

```
def shut_down(s):    
    if s == "yes"
```

It is recommended to use 4 spaces for indentation in Python, tabulation or a different number of spaces may work, but it is also known to cause trouble at times. more on that can be read on [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation).

I'm not exactly sure how you tried to indent your second line, but it is important to note that most modern Python IDEs will automatically replace your tabs with 4 spaces, which is great if you're used to tabbing (I personally use PyCharm, but IDLE does that as well).

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are a very beginner in Python function definition , The correct way to define function is :

```
    #function definition
    def shut_down(s): 
      if s=="yes" :
        print("right")
      return 

    shut_down("yes")  #calling the function
```

Here during function call you assign the "yes" to **s** variable.

Comment: File "<stdin>", line 2
    if s == "yes":
     ^

Comment: File "<stdin>", line 2
    if s == "yes":
     ^ I am getting this error on second line.

Comment: def shut_down(s):
    if s == "yes":
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    if s == "yes":
     ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Comment: Thanks Occasus & Borris, I got it now. It was the problem with my editor.I have put 3 space only,when I used tab it was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Give a space or tab.
Python enforces indentation.
... does not means that cursor is moved ahead but that you are writing for a block.

Copy following two code snippet and try running

```
def shut_down(s):
print "Indentation Error"
```

[Indentation Error Demo](http://ideone.com/imGsMu)

```
def shut_down(s):
    print "No Indentation Error"
```

[No Error Demo](http://ideone.com/sK9215)